# Getting Compile Error for "CG_INLINE bool" - Unknown type name CG_INLINE

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, struct

I attached an image with the compile error I get.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CG_INLINE` is defined in `CoreGraphics/CGBase.h`. Are you importing CoreGraphics? Alternatively, why not just use `static inline` instead?

Comment: Forgot to import it in the class itself. Thanks for your tip.